# Visual C++ - Find out if started by debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I'd like to use

```
AllocConsole();
```

or

```
AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
```

depending on if the program was run within visual studio. AttachConsole will not print output to any of the windows like "output". So I'd like to use AllocConsole instead so I get a console window at least.

I found solutions for C# but not for C++ NOT using .NET.

Thanks for answers.
I'd appreciate other ways for logging program stuff except writing to files, too :-)

Kai

Comment: Maybe it would be better to tell us the end result you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to display something in the debugger if it's present?

Comment: Use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why don't you just ask for a console window so it is all automatic?  Project + Properties, Linker, System, SubSystem = Console.

Comment: Thanks paulm. This is exatly what I was searching for :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log "stuff" so it's visible in the debugger (if one is present) then you probably want to use [`OutputDebugString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx).

Comment: This one helped me pretty much for this case. Thanks. But what do I do when I need to know whether the program is being debugged or not? Is there a way such as in C#?

Comment: @Silberling: [`IsDebuggerPresent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345.aspx)